# The image may be incomplete: <marker> is not supported

Tags: android, svg

I am trying to import a svg file to android studio but it loses quality.
[image]This is how it should look like above.
[image] [image]and these are how it looks like on preview and once it's imported.
If you look at the second image, you can see "The image may be incomplete: Error @ line 5:  is not supported" this error message. I assume this is the problem but I am not able to find any solution to it.
My android studio version: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1.
I will appreciate it if you could give me any help. Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]
Here is the code for that svg file.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="640dp"
    android:height="480dp"
    android:viewportWidth="640"
    android:viewportHeight="480">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#bd3d44"
        android:pathData="M0,0h640v480H0" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M0,55.3h640M0,129h640M0,203h640M0,277h640M0,351h640M0,425h640"
        android:strokeWidth="37"
        android:strokeColor="#fff" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#192f5d"
        android:pathData="M0,0h364.8v258.5H0" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="m14,0 l9,27L0,10h28L5,27z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Can you share the SVG file?

Comment: Yes, please share the code. But my guess would be that the stars are placed on one or more paths or polygon lines where a marker/the star sits on each point on that line. If marker is not supported an alternative could be to use a pattern (test if that is supported first) or just place the stars with individual use elements. But this is just an error in Android Studio -- could the file actually work in production?

Comment: I updated with the code for that svg file.

Comment: The last path seems to be the part to draw a star. @chrwahl I have no clue how to implement a pattern there. The file displays just one star as it is shown in the preview window in the device/emulator. Since this is just a toy project just for me, I don't have production and don't have clue if it would work in different environment(like production even if exists).